# Adding element in a list using hash table

Tags: java, hashtable

I want to insert an element in my list through hashing, when the element is already in the list, the list will not create duplicates. The element must be placed on the **last position** in my list. However, my code just insert in any position in my list. I do not know where I got wrong in my code.

```
boolean add(T key) {

        int position = getHash(key);

        if(table[position] == null) {
            table[position] = new Node(key);
        } else {
            Node element = table[position];
            while(element.next != null && !element.key.equals(key))
                element = element.next;
            if(element.key.equals(key))
                return false;
            else
                element.next = new Node(size);
        }
        size++;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide complete snippet of code, which demonstrates the problem? A complete class with main method and Node as inner class for example. And also input which reproduces the bug

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Have a look what's `next` and `element`'s value after your loop ends.

Comment: I think you need to present some input/output that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Snippets of code are seldom useful.  Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  And to emphasize, `short, compilable, and runnable`.